# Cannot draw around the screen after zooming out with LibGDX projection coordinate

Tags: android, libgdx

I've just started developing game in android using LibGDX.
I've follow some samples and now my simple game can draw path when user move their finger around the screen.

now problems appear when i add another feature to allow user to **pinch zoom in and out**.
after zooming OUT the orthographic camera user can still draw the path BUT
the path can no longer follow user finger to the edge of the screen, the user can only draw the path around the center of the screen. looks like the coordinate projection after zoom out not changed and still limited to the projection before zoom out!

how can i make my game to keep drawing line around the entire screen even after the user have zooming out the camera?

here's my code:

*1.* in my `Screen` implemented class:

```
@Override
public void render(float arg0) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    renderer.render();
}


@Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        isDrawing = true;

        Vector2 v = new Vector2(screenX, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-screenY);

        //add new point for drawing path
        inputPoints.insert(v);

        return true;
    }
```

*2.* in my `Renderer` class:

```
cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    this.cam.update();

public void setZoom(float zoom) {
     this.cam.zoom = zoom;
     this.cam.update();
 }

//the triangle strip renderer
    path = new PathClass();

public void render() {
    cam.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    //generate the triangle strip from our path
    Array<Vector2> xox = screen.path();
    path.update(xox);

    //the vertex color for tinting, i.e. for opacity
    path.color = Color.WHITE;

    //render the triangles to the screen
    path.draw(cam);
}
```

*3.* on my `PathClass`:

```
public void draw(Camera cam) {
    if (tristrip.size<=0)
        return;

    gl20.begin(cam.combined, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for (int i=0; i<tristrip.size; i++) {
        if (i==batchSize) {
            gl20.end();
            gl20.begin(cam.combined, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        }   
        Vector2 point = tristrip.get(i);
        gl20.color(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);
        gl20.vertex(point.x, point.y, 0f);
    }
    gl20.end();
}
```

Comment: Did you eventually figure this out?

Comment: If you did you could post the answer to your problem and I will up vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3 v = new Vector3(screenX, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-screenY, 0);

camera.unproject(v);//converts v to world coords
```